# usage of + in Posix Regex library

Tags: c, regex, regex-greedy

This should be pretty simple, but I am having trouble understanding the basic working of '+' in regex.h library in C. Not sure what is going wrong.

Pasting a sample code which doesn't work. I want to find a string which starts with B and ends with A, there can be more than one occurrence of B so I want to use B+

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
regex_t regex;
int reti;

/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^B+A$", 0);
if( reti)
{
    printf("Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, "BBBA", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti )
{
    printf("Match\n");
}
else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH )
{
    printf("No match\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Regex match failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
regfree(&regex);
return 0;
}
```

This does not find the match, but I am not able to understand why.

Usage of ^BB*A$ works fine, but that is not something I would want. 
As I also want to check for something like ^[BCD]+A$ which should match BBBA or CCCCA or DDDDA. Usage of ^[BCD][BCD]*A$ wont work for me as that could match BCCCA which is not the desired match.
Tried using parentheses and brackets in the expression but it doesn't seem to help.

Quick help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is a POSIX regex what GNU `grep` accepts?  Because it does not treat `+` (or `?` for that matter) as metacharacters -- you have to either escape them with a backslash, or turn on "Extended Regular Expressions" with `-E`.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. I will modify the code based on your comments and Alp's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `regcomp()` compiles a pattern as a so-called [Basic Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03); in such regular expressions the `+` operator is not available.  The regex syntax you're trying to use is known as [Extended Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) syntax.  In order to have `regcomp()` work with that more extended syntax you need to pass it the `REG_EXTENDED` flag.

By the way, this comment:

> As I also want to check for something like ^[BCD]+A$ which should match BBBA or CCCCA or 
>   DDDDA. Usage of ^[BCD][BCD]*A$ wont work for me as that could match BCCCA which is not the 
>   desired match

is based on a misconception of how the quantifiers `+` and `*` work.  The regular expressions `^[BCD]+A$` and `^[BCD][BCD]*A$` are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for helping Alp. This clarifies my confusion now. I will modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I don't have enough rep points, to upvote your answer.